# Question about Warlock/Arcane trickster spells

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock, multi-classing, rogue

I am a Rogue level 7 arcane trickster/level 1 warlock. So, can I go into any warlock spell of level one and how any spells am I able to know at this level?

Comment: Do you have the Players Handbook?

Comment: Please add clarification or elaborate on the question.  Are you asking if an arcane trickster can select known spells from the warlock list?  or are you asking if the warlock slots could be used to cast the arcane trickster spells?

Comment: It would be useful to make the title of the question a question.

Comment: Please review these three pages ([56-58 in the SRD](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf#page=56)), and then edit your question to add a little more detail regarding what about multiclassing you are finding confusing. We have quite a few multiclassing questions; it's not uncommon for this choice to lead to questions.

Answer (score 1):

Track your Warlock and Arcane Trickster spells completely separately. They use different rules (Warlocks have "Pact Magic", which *is similar to but not the same as* regular Spellcasting), so the multiclassing rules for Spellcasting don't even apply in this situation.

So, as a level 7 Arcane Trickster, level 1 Warlock, you have the following:

- 5 Level 1 Spell Slots, one (and only one) of which can be recovered on a Short Rest; the remaining 4 may only recover on a Long Rest.
- 2 Level 2 Spell slots, recoverable on a Long Rest.
- 5 Known Cantrips:

  - 1 must be Mage Hand,
  - 2 are pulled at your discretion from the Wizard spell list, and use your Intelligence as Spellcasting Modifier,
  - 2 are pulled at your discretion from the Warlock spell list, which use your Charisma as Spellcasting Modifier
- 7 Known Spells, which are:

  - 2 First Level **Warlock Spells**, which use your Charisma as Spellcasting Modifier
  - 4 **Wizard Spells** which must be Enchantment or Illusion Spells; they use your Intelligence as Spellcasting Modifier
    2 of which *may be* **Second Level Spells** or **First Level Spells**
    2 of which *must be* **First Level Spells**
  - 1 First Level **Wizard Spell**, which may come from any Spell School, so long as it is accessible to Wizards; Intelligence as Spellcasting Modifier.

Let me know if any of this is unclear.